# Accessing a child object inside of fields_for (Rails 2.3.11)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested form on my edit action for a class called CustomOrder. CustomOrder accepts nested_attributes_for CustomSizes which belongs to Size and Style classes.

Right now I'm able to retrieve the records with their corresponding style_id, size_id, and quantities.

```
- f.fields_for :custom_sizes do |b|
%t
  %td
    = b.text_field :style_id
  %td
    = b.text_field :size_id
      %td
    = b.text_field :quantity
```

What I really want to do though, is show the user the corresponding Style and Size objects here, and hide the text_fields. Something like this:

```
- f.fields_for :custom_sizes do |b, custom_size|
%tr
  %td
    = custom_size.style.name
  %td
    = custom_size.size.name
  %td
    = b.text_field :quantity
```

Any way for me to access the child objects during the fields_for loop?

Comment: you need custom_size.object.style.name

Comment: Thanks VelLes. For my example, it was actually b.object.style.name